Insulation pushing out underneath built-in shelving in garage
pushing out from underneath some built-in shelving in our garage. Today there is more of this material where I had removed it before - I'm convinced it's insulation from the wall. This home was built in 1989 in CA. I called an insulation company for an estimate. I'm wondering if it's safe for me or our caregiver (we're caring for my elderly mother) to go into the garage to get items that we need. I'm also wondering if it's safe for us to use items in the garage like laundry or food storage items, etc. or if we need to wash them thoroughly or throw them away.
I would like to remove the built in shelving units anyways and replace them. I'm wondering if it's safe for me to go out with a mask to throw things away.
Thank you for any knowledge you can share about this topic!

Pictures would help a lot. From 1989 it is unlikely to be really nasty stuff, but anything is possible. More likely is some sort of foam, cellulose or fiberglass. All of which are OK unless you start eating them or grinding them up and breathing them.

Pictures will be nice, but by 89 most insulation should be safe to be around.  Some will feel like itching powder if you play around on it.  It is odd for insulation to push out after 30 years.  Masks/gloves/eye protection are recommended for working with insulation/any stuff, but more for safety/comfort than health(make you sick) concerns.  The only insulation that pushes out is the spray foam types, but that is when being installed/sprayed, not after 30 years.

You sure there ain't some critters in there?
